# Why can I use this webhook in Postman and not in TradingView alerts?

Tags: pine-script, alert, webhooks, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

When I send this POST using POSTMAN the text 'Hello World' is added to a Google Sheet.

```
https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwXdAoAnggrOL2NXhyIi7L2uQKKv4bmZjg_Z67VYi6jUuNp5HmiTw78ARGVZWSHYaM7/exec?gid=2061&Message=Hello World
```

I have tried to use this as webhook URL in TradingView:

```
https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwXdAoAnggrOL2NXhyIi7L2uQKKv4bmZjg_Z67VYi6jUuNp5HmiTw78ARGVZWSHYaM7/exec?
```

and add the gid and Message as message in the Pine script alert function but without success.
I have tried a lot of different ways but nothing gets written to the Google sheet.

```
if DiffCloseMA > 0
    alert ("gid=2061&Message=Buy", alert.freq_once_per_bar)
else if DiffCloseMA < 0
    alert ("gid=2061&Message=Sell", alert.freq_once_per_bar)
```

Have someone solved something similar?
Thanks!

EDIT:
Got it to work using this script

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay = true)
DiffCloseMA = close-ta.sma(close,10)

datanew = '{"Message": "Hello World"}'

if DiffCloseMA > 0
    alert (datanew, alert.freq_once_per_bar)
else if DiffCloseMA < 0
    alert (datanew, alert.freq_once_per_bar)

plot(ta.sma(close,5))

and this as web hook URL
https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzqdmXRkOQ5HiBegwKnQMg_kO7o5OFGmdM_aW8IRapSD-5k-wVGLeMG7mAwJ6A/exec
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TradingView server, from which the POST is done, as no authorization to post to your google sheet.

For posting from pinescript, I format my message like this (be carefull it is not a message for a google sheet) :

```
datanew = '{
              "client": client_id, 
              "apiKey": client_API_Key, 
              "secretKey": client_Secret_Key,
              "command": "batch_cancel_active_order",
              "symbol": symbol,
              "side": side,
              "orderCategory" : orderCategory 
              }'
alert(datanew, alert.freq_once_per_bar)
```

Comment: I have reinstalled the Google Drive extension that creates the web hook and set the permissions on the Google sheet so that anyone can edit. Still noting gets written.

When I use Postman I can write no matter what permission is set on the sheet. And I am not logged on to Postman using the Google account. I assume anyone having access to the long code (AKfycbwXdAoAnggrOL2NXhyIi7L2uQKKv4bmZjg_Z67VYi6jUuNp5HmiTw78ARGVZWSHYaM7) can send data. But some how the message from Trading View is not formatted correct I guess.

Comment: This is the extension I am using:
https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/webhooks_for_sheets/860288437469

Comment: @Paddy I update my answer with how I form message in pinescript for the webhook.